# Deploy Andorid/iOS app on free Heroku account for Stripe payments

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

I'm creating an application for Android/iOS both and implemented Stripe for payments, so I've deployed it on Heroku for free.

So my concern is that can I run Stripe on the free account (Heroku) without any issues (means we can deploy/run application by using live secret key as well or is it only for testing purpose) or do I need to use my personal paid server for the Stripe deployment to interconnect with android/iOS apps.

Referring to this link: [Stripe for free - Example App Backend (Deploy to Heroku)](https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend)

and what does this sentence mean

> This is intended for example purposes only: you'll likely need something more serious for your production apps.

which is available on the above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the `stripe/example-ios-backend` codebase (Ruby), so after spending a lot of time by searching on Internet and also talking with support team, I found a solution with the help of Stripe Support Team.

So, the solution was just need to update the currency in [`web.rb` file of Ruby project (Example Stripe Codebase)](https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend/blob/master/web.rb#L48) and redeploy the changed code to Heroku.

Steps to follow:

1. Install Heroku on your local system
2. Login Heroku by using `heroku login` and enter your credentials
3. `clone` the Heroku app locally by using this command `heroku git:clone -a <your-app-name>`
4. pull the latest code from here Example iOS Backend Codebase and put it into the Heroku project `<your-app-name>`
5. After that change `"currency" : "usd"` to `"currency" : "eur"` on line number 48
6. `commit` your changes and push `git push heroku master`

and that's it!